# Bash script using awk doesn't read the entire line, just the first column

Tags: bash, awk

There's a file to be processed, columns are separated by tabs:

```
$ cat system.log
2       camila  create db
3       andrew  create table
5       greg    update table
6       nataly  update view
7       greg    delete table
9       camila  update table
11      nataly  create view
12      peter   link table
14      andrew  update view
15      greg    update db
```

I wanted these lines displayed in a form:

```
Entry No. 7: camila (action: create db)
```

To do so, I created the following bash script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

filename=$1

while read line; do
        printf $line | awk -F '\t' '{ print "Entry No. ", $1, ": ", $2, " (action: ", $3, ")" }'
done < $filename
```

However, what I get is:

```
$ ./log_parser.sh system.log
Entry No.  2 :    (action:   )
Entry No.  3 :    (action:   )
Entry No.  5 :    (action:   )
Entry No.  6 :    (action:   )
Entry No.  7 :    (action:   )
Entry No.  9 :    (action:   )
Entry No.  11 :    (action:   )
Entry No.  12 :    (action:   )
Entry No.  14 :    (action:   )
Entry No.  15 :    (action:   )
```

Why only the first column gets processed and what to do to have the whole line processed?

Comment: You could just use: `awk -F '\t' '{print "Entry No.", $1, ":", $2, "(action: ", $3, ")"}' system.log`

Comment: I know, but this is a part of a bigger script.

Comment: If `line` has the contents `2 camila create db`, then `printf $line` is the same as `printf 2 camila create db` which (correctly) just writes `2`.  Quote your variables to prevent word splitting, but use `printf '%s' "$line"`.  But don't do that at all.  Drop the `while/read` loop and just use `awk`.

Comment: Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about - that will solve some of your problems. Also see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for why not to use your current approach at all though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Failing to wrap `$line` in double quotes causes the `\t` characters to be replaced with spaces, which in turn screws up the `awk -F'\t'`.

Consider:

```
$ line=$(head -1 system.log)

# double quoting ${line} maintains the \t characters:

$ echo "${line}" | od -c
0000000   2  \t   c   a   m   i   l   a  \t   c   r   e   a   t   e
0000020   d   b  \n
0000023

# no (double) quoting of ${line} replaces the \t with spaces:

$ echo ${line} | od -c
0000000   2       c   a   m   i   l   a       c   r   e   a   t   e
0000020   d   b  \n
0000023
```

The issue is further compounded by how `printf` handles the unquoted `${line}`, eg:

```
$ printf ${line}
2

$ printf "${line}"
2       camila  create db
```

As for the whole `while` loop, and assuming the sole purpose of the `while` loop is to send the modified file contents to stdout (ie, you're not using `${line}` for other bash-level operations), you could replace the whole thing with a single `awk` call, eg:

```
$ awk -F '\t' '{ print "Entry No. ", $1, ": ", $2, " (action: ", $3, ")" }' system.log
Entry No.  2 :  camila  (action:  create db )
Entry No.  3 :  andrew  (action:  create table )
Entry No.  5 :  greg  (action:  update table )
Entry No.  6 :  nataly  (action:  update view )
Entry No.  7 :  greg  (action:  delete table )
Entry No.  9 :  camila  (action:  update table )
Entry No.  11 :  nataly  (action:  create view )
Entry No.  12 :  peter  (action:  link table )
Entry No.  14 :  andrew  (action:  update view )
Entry No.  15 :  greg  (action:  update db )
```

**NOTE:** the extra spaces in the output are due to how the `print` command is being built; separating each argument with a `,` adds the default `awk/OFS` delimiter (a space) between each argument; removing the comma (`awk/OFS` delimiter) generates:

```
$ awk -F '\t' '{ print "Entry No. " $1 ": " $2 " (action: " $3 ")" }' system.log
Entry No. 2: camila (action: create db)
Entry No. 3: andrew (action: create table)
Entry No. 5: greg (action: update table)
Entry No. 6: nataly (action: update view)
Entry No. 7: greg (action: delete table)
Entry No. 9: camila (action: update table)
Entry No. 11: nataly (action: create view)
Entry No. 12: peter (action: link table)
Entry No. 14: andrew (action: update view)
Entry No. 15: greg (action: update db)
```

Answer (score 2):

You must quote your variables to prevent word splitting.  Consider if `$line` evaluates to the string `2       camila  create db`.  In that case, `printf $line` is equivalent to `printf 2 camila create db` which calls `printf` with 4 arguments.  `printf` correctly parses those arguments and dutifully writes the string `2`. If you want to pass a single argument to `printf`, you could do `printf "$line"`.  But that is also incorrect, as the first argument to `printf` should be a format string, and you don't want to use input strings as format strings.  Instead, you should write `printf '%s' "$line"`.  But don't do that, either. `while read; printf | awk` is an anti-pattern.  Just use `awk` to read the input.